# Получаю непонятный ответ в VBA ResponseText

Tags: vba

Делаю запрос на JSON API, чтобы получить ответ в виде json.
Получаю старнный набор символов

[image: Вот такой ответ получаю в итоге]

пытался Спарсить через JSON Parse Master, он выдаёт ошибку. Кто может помочь?

Вот код:

```
Dim objHTTP2 As Object
    Dim URL2 As String
    Set objHTTP2 = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL2 = "site.com/api"
    objHTTP2.Open "GET", URL2, False
    objHTTP2.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

    objHTTP2.send
    
    Dim Json As Object
    
    
    response = objHTTP2.responseText
    'Dim Resp As Object
    'Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objHTTP2.responseText)
    
    Debug.Print response
```

Comment: возьмите Ваш `site.com/api` откройте постман или на худой конец браузер и посмотрите что вернется по этому адресу

Comment: Постман всё выводит, и powershell выводит правильный JSON, а вот VBA в Exel не хочет этого делать выводит хрен пойти что

Comment: Так в VBA нет responseJSON

Comment: Я когда пытался запарсить это всё, он выдавал ошибку в самом модуле парсера. Он не понимал наверно что делать надо с этими символами. 
Если поставлю SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
То вместо символо будут ???????????? и пару букв

Comment: Если мой ответ помог Вам решить задачу, пожалуйста отметьте его как правильный

Comment: Я понял в чём проблема , это всё из-за того что он получает ответ в gzip компресии . А как её убрать буду искать дальше, а так спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Да очень похоже на бинарные данные, думаю можно запустить внешний скрипт, попробую глянуть что можно сделать, можете ссылочку дать на api? и где именно Вы запускает скрипт, я могу проверить только локально на Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `JSON` это объект `JavaScript` можно попробовать его распрарсить через вычисление скрипта:

```
Set MyScript = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
MyScript.Language = "JScript"
Set response = MyScript.Eval("(" + objHTTP2.responsetext + ")")
Debug.Print response
```